# Displaying an image in erb that's hosted elsewhere online

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a little trouble trying to display an image that is hosted on another site. Usually I would have the image in my assets pipeline, but on this project I am using an API to grab the image URL that's hosted on another site. I'm trying it this way below, but I feel like it's still pointing to my assets folder. How can I set it to display this image if it meets a conditional? Thanks!

```
...

<% if article.image_url %>    
  <%= image_url("<%= article.image_url %>") %><p>
<% end %>

...
```

Comment: Which hosting service are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd need to interpolate `article.image_url` like so:

```
<% if article.image_url %>    
  <%= image_tag article.image_url %><p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The interpolation of a string-valued expression into a string is exactly the same as the expression alone.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<%= image_tag(article.image_url) if article.image_url %>`

Hope this helps!